# Simple multi-threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I have a class called Movement which moves a picture box (guy on the left) on my form to a random position when it's Lead method gets executed. I also have a method which moves another picture box (dark guy on the right) called SetMrShadowToMove. These two picture boxes are suppose to move at the same time and arrive at the random point (one point for both picture boxes) at the same time.

[image]

For now, these methods use a timer to move the picture boxes, but my main intention was to have a loop which runs until the picture box's coordinates meet the random point picked while using Thread.Sleep to delay the process and make an animation of it.

To do that, I need to run both methods on different threads, so my UI thread doesn't get frozen and these methods would run at the same time.

My problem is that I don't know how to run these methods on different threads, and also don't know how to access the picture boxes on the other threads (it seems that this has something to do with invoking and stuff!).

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: The best way is not using winforms for creating games

Comment: This is not a game, just a practice animation to learn multi-threading and some other stuff.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18702/Threading-in-NET-and-WinForms

Answer (score 1):

The best way (in my opinion) is by using a background worker.

those things can do there calculations in the background. If you you want to update the interface after that you can use there report progress event to invoke your main (interface) thread and redraw the screen. You can also the work complete even if you want to have a event of the background worker as a final even (for example if mister shadow is 'destroyed' or something).

I don't know your code of mister shadow so I don't have any direct example code for you. But a full example about how to use a background worker can be found on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). I hope this will help you.

Comment: Well actually the main goal here is to create a walking animation. That's why I need to update the main thread in each execution of my loop. Consider a while loop that runs until X and Y are equal to RndX and RndY. With each run of the loop the picture box's X or Left value and Y or Top value gets incremented or decremented based on the RndX and RndY. The important thing here is to update UI after each time the picture box moves.

Comment: what decides if the picture box moves? Is it the entity of the picture box itself that should run in the background? If so you can create the loop in the dowork event. In that loop you calculate where the picture box should go and what image should be displayed for the animation. This information you send to the report progress event and you have that one update your GUI. If you make the sleep in the iteration not to long it could be kind of smooth (keep in mind though you never get full smooth animation in forms, you need different things then a picture box and windows forms.

Comment: The picture boxes are supposed to start to move AT THE SAME TIME on Form_Load. And they will keep moving until the application gets terminated by the user. If I use the DoWork event of BackgroundWorker class, and I use Thread.Sleep in a loop inside DoWork (the loop I discussed in the previous comment), how would I access/invoke my picture boxes to change their picture? And beside the backgroundworker solution, how would I achieve the same thing using simple threads running at the same time? If you are interested I can show you my whole code (it's not much btw) for clarification.

Comment: In that case you want to get a so called simulation cycle. Basically what you do is you create a background worker. it loops 'infinatly'. inside i you call the report progress event. In that event you have it pull all the data of where certain image boxes should be and you have it draw it (move the picture boxes, changes there images and so on). A full explanation can be found here: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/130247/multithreaded_game_engine_.php?page=2  (note the article is not written by me, I just found it with Google)